# Don't share artifacts between different architectures in gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I have a project that builds in different docker environments and want to pass artifacts to the next stage. Gitlab-Ci is mixing artifacts and pass them alltogether to the next step. How to avoid this?

[image: gitlab pipeline representation]

I guess there should be a way to pass artifact from build_mt31 to the acceptance_mt31 and same for mt32 path. Gitlab instead passes them all to all siblings:

```
Downloading artifacts for build_mt31 (6965)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=6965 responseStatus=200 OK token=26sk7GBS
Downloading artifacts for build_mt32 (6966)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=6966 responseStatus=200 OK token=7EDnce-d
```

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yaml file:

```
stages:
  - build
  - acceptance

build_mt31:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - mt3.1
    - docker
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
    paths:
    - bld31/
  script:
    - rm -rf bld31
    - mkdir -p bld31
    - cd bld31
    - touch build_mt31

acceptance_mt31:
  stage: acceptance
  tags:
    - mt3.1
    - docker
  script:
    - cd bld31
    - ls -all

build_mt32:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - mt3.2
    - docker
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
    paths:
    - bld32/
  script:
    - rm -rf bld32
    - mkdir -p bld32
    - cd bld32
    - touch build_mt32

acceptance_mt32:
  stage: acceptance
  tags:
    - mt3.2
    - docker
  script:
    - cd bld32
    - ls -all
```

Ideally instead of having bld31, 32 I would call directories with the same name, but in the current setup they will overwrite each other when passing to the next step.

Answer (score 7):

You want to use the `dependencies` [keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#dependencies), it  allows you to define the artifacts to pass between different jobs.

For example, you can use it like this:

```
acceptance_mt32:
  stage: acceptance
  dependencies:
    - build_mt32
```

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @rpadovani I have added dependencies still my pipelines are intermixing. Can you suggest something ?